# Using Scrapy to login to a web site, navigate to a javascript form, select options, and then scrape data displayed

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to use Scrapy to log into my university account, navigate to the class enrollment page, select a certain term and course subject, submit those options, and then scrape the page which contains listed classes for information about those classes. So far I have this to log into my account:

```
import scrapy

class myuh(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'myuh.com'
start_urls = ['https://my.uh.edu/psp/paprd/?cmd=login']

def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'userid': 'MYLOGINID', 'pwd': 'MYPASSWORD'},
        callback=self.after_login
    )

def after_login(self, response):
    # check login succeed before going on
    if "authentication failed" in response.body:
        self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
        return
```

I need to navigate to [this page](https://my.uh.edu/psp/paprd/UHM_SITE/HRMS/c/SA_LEARNER_SERVICES.CLASS_SEARCH.GBL?PORTALPARAM_PTCNAV=HC_CLASS_SEARCH&EOPP.SCNode=ENTP&EOPP.SCPortal=UHM_SITE&EOPP.SCName=ADMN_LEARNER_SERVICES&EOPP.SCLabel=Enrollment&EOPP.SCFName=ADMN_F200608071533295113986632&EOPP.SCSecondary=true&EOPP.SCPTcname=PT_PTPP_SCFNAV_BASEPAGE_SCR&FolderPath=PORTAL_ROOT_OBJECT.HCCC_ENROLLMENT.HC_CLASS_SEARCH&IsFolder=false).

while still being logged in and then select options from the javascript form on that page and hit submit. I think I have figured out that I can use Selenium to submit the form, but I can't figure out how to navigate to that web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info) in addition to Scrapy (or something simpler if you only need to parse the page).